# Spring mvc upload multiple files at once with AJAX doesn't work

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, tomcat, dropzone.js, dropzone

I'm using Spring boot 2.0.1 and I'm trying to upload multiple files with dropzone. Everything is working perfectly when I'm using  `uploadMultiple: false` on `Dropzone.js`. When I set `uploadMultiple: true`, My Controller stops working.

The controller class is as follow:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/img/upload")
public ResponseEntity<?> fileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile[] files){

    System.out.println(files.length);
    for (MultipartFile file : files) {
        try {
            file.transferTo(new File("/opt/img/" + file.getOriginalFilename()));
            System.out.println(file.getOriginalFilename());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>("File Uploaded Successfully.", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The files are no more than 1MB and my settings are

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```

My request header when I upload the files:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryihPcX9WHR5UA9jGD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file[0]"; filename="cars-02-01.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryihPcX9WHR5UA9jGD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file[1]"; filename="Screenshot from 2018-05-03 23-31-53.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

Everything seems perfect. I still cannot find the reason for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that I should use the `MultipartHttpServletRequest` instead of `MultipartFile[] files`. I Changed the method to:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/img/upload")
public ResponseEntity<?> fileUpload(MultipartHttpServletRequest request) {
    Map<String, MultipartFile> fileMap = request.getFileMap();

    for (MultipartFile file : fileMap.values()) {
        try {
            file.transferTo(new File("/opt/img/" + file.getOriginalFilename()));
            System.out.println(file.getOriginalFilename());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>("File Uploaded Successfully.", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```